# stop editing of datepicker and combobox fields without disabling them

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'd like to "disable" a datepicker and combobox (dropdown) without "disabling" it. The reason is, is that they grey out and you can't read them properly.

I'd like the same functionality as when you set a Textfield "non-editable":

```
textField.setEditable(false)
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the `DatePicker` and then style it to look like normal:

```
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
datePicker.setDisable(true);
datePicker.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1.0");
```

When you disable a `Node`, JavaFX sets its opacity to `0.4`; you can just set it right back where it came from.

If you are still wanting to allow a user to select a date with the dropdown but not type their own date, just set the `editable` property:

```
datePicker.setEditable(false);
```